# Nested ng-repeat with array of objects which contain arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't get nested `ng-repeat` to work for a data-structure like the following:

```
options = [{name:"opt1", data:["a","b","c"]}, {name:"op2", data:["d","e","f"]}]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a select tag for each entry with options in it.

I thought that something like this should work:

```
<label ng-repeat="option in options">
  <div>{{option.name}}</div>
  <select>
    <option ng-repreat="val in option.data">{{val}}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

but only the name is name is printed properly and only one option with no value in it is created.

Then I tried using `track by $index` in the inner `ng-repeat`:

```
<label ng-repeat="option in options">
  <div>{{option.name}}</div>
  <select>
    <option ng-repreat="val in option.data track by $index">
      {{option.data[$index]}}
    </option>
  </select>
</label>
```

but `$index` appears to be the outer `$index` and only counts from 0 to 1 with the given data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a typo `ng-repreat` should be `ng-repeat`

Comment: You should be using [**`select's ng-option`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: @Chandermani that's embarassing^^ now it works :) Thank you!

Comment: `<select ng-options="val for val in option.data"></select>` should work, right? Because it's not^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use ng-options instead of ng-repeat and with the help of ng-model you can get selected value. Here is a working code

```js
angular.module("module", []).controller('mainCtr', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.options = [{name:"opt1", data:["a","b","c"]}, {name:"op2", data:["d","e","f"]}];
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="module">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js">    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainCtr">
        <div ng-repeat="option in options">
            <div>{{option.name}}</div>
            <select ng-model="opt" ng-options="opt for opt in option.data">
                <option value="">--- select ---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the answer, but how can you get both array of options in one select, not two but one. Is it possible through html binding or better to prepare the new array in the controller? Thanks : )